# SampleData elm package?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to run the force directed graph from the [elm visualisations](https://elm-visualization.netlify.app/) examples.

However I can't identify what package the `SampleData` dependency is from.

```
...
import SampleData exposing (miserablesGraph)
...
```

Could I get a point in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be something internal because [examples on the Github](https://github.com/gampleman/elm-visualization/blob/master/examples/ForceDirectedGraph.elm#L238) have this data hardcoded.

I'd suggest doing the same in your code. Either define `miserablesGraph` function:

```
miserablesGraph : Graph String ()
miserablesGraph =
    Graph.fromNodeLabelsAndEdgePairs
        [ "Myriel"
        , "Napoleon"
        , "Mlle.Baptistine"
...
```

or create `SampleData` module and define the function there.

```
module SampleData exposing (miserablesGraph)

miserablesGraph : Graph String ()
miserablesGraph =
    Graph.fromNodeLabelsAndEdgePairs
        [ "Myriel"
        , "Napoleon"
        , "Mlle.Baptistine"
...
```